# Vertically flowing text with css

Tags: css

I would like to have a div with some text in it. But I'd like the text to flow vertically instead of horizontally. Like this;

M

y

t

e

x

t

Any ideas on how to accomplish this with CSS?

Answer (score 5):

If you have only one *line* of text you could try using `width:1em;letter-spacing:1px` (and a space between each letter)

edit: if you want to use no space between each letter `width:1em;letter-spacing:1em;word-wrap:break-word`

Comment: try with 0.9em and add a space between each letter (or use a custom letter-spacing) // check my update

Comment: Yes well a space between each letter kind of defeats the whole purpose, of course it'll work with a space between each letter. :(

Comment: Did you try to combine it with "word-wrap: break-word"? Note that this will only work in IE and CSS3-compatible browsers.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 has a proposed 'writing-mode' attribute that can be set to 'tb-lr' (write text from top to bottom, write lines from left to right), but I don't know if any browsers support it yet, so its not something to rely on.

Comment: The IEs support writing-mode, but other browsers do not yet.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 }
```

```html
<div>Jelly</div>
```

Please find the answer here you can use text-orientation and

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourtext { -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-transform-origin: top right;
            -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Comment: That just rotates the entire text, it won't rotate the letters back.