# Vertical orientation text in css

Tags: css

I can't believe no one ever asked this so I just assume I don't know the correct name for what I want. I'd like to have a text like `jelly` to be vertical aligned like this:

```
j
e
l
l
y
```

Is there a cross browser solution?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css/

Comment: Do you want the one on left or right? http://www.thinkingwithtype.com/images/Thinking_with_Type_Text_22.gif

Comment: @nhahtdh I want the one on the left

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508803/vertically-flowing-text-with-css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an article that details several ways to accomplish this with both CSS and javascript along with the pros and cons of each.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css/

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do it is to using `text-orientation`.  (See snippet or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu7qr809/).)

```css
  p {
    text-orientation: upright;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  }
```

```html
<p>Jelly</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
p{
    width:5px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/TWb9j/

Comment: Since break-word is part of the CSS3 spec it won't be compliant across all browsers.

Comment: also, if it's several words with spaces, you'll need to change spaces with &nbsp;

Comment: @gizmovation who said break-word is part of css3. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: @sandeep I must be missing something. Doesn't the article you linked show that word-wrap:break-word IS css3? Here is another link to show when different css props were introduced. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp

Comment: @gizmovation never trust on w3school check this why http://w3fools.com/. You can check my example with different browsers.

Comment: @sandeep, look at example how ussual space between words is shown: http://jsfiddle.net/ZA6TS/