# Japanese subtitles vertical alignment

Tags: jquery, vertical-alignment, subtitle

I am working with jquery.

If I have a string like this:

```
新しい世界へようこそ。
```

Would it be possible to take each character, place it vertically in a div so I get vertical subtitles?

So that the correct formatting would be achieved? (I am not familiar with Japanese language)

Comment: `p { writing-mode: tb-rl; }` ?

Comment: http://generatedcontent.org/post/45384206019/writing-modes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2508803/1402846

Answer (score 0):

`<p>新しい世界へようこそ。</p>`

```
p { 
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; 
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/X78vC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://generatedcontent.org/post/45384206019/writing-modes).

```
 <div >こんいちわ 「1234」 １０月２０１４年</div>

div {
-ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; /* old syntax. IE */
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* new syntax */
}
```

**UPDATE**

After some more experimentation, I realize that specifying `text-direction` is not a good idea.
Chrome on linux, displays halfwidth latin characters sideways, but full-width characters upright.

In the example, the `1234` is rotated sideways, but the `１０月２０１４年` is shown vertically. Not specifying direction lets the browser do 'The Right Thing'.

http://jsfiddle.net/X78vC/3/

Chrome doesn't seem to let you do some interesting things, like squish 2 half-width numerals on to a single line - I wonder if ligatures could solve that at some point.
Some good examples of vertical writing in Japanese are given [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Jun/0133.html).

Comment: @toniq That's the way japanese is written vertically.

Comment: @toniq: Hmmm... It's actually more complicated than I thought. [This](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Jun/0133.html) shows some variations, in some examples text is partly upright, and partly sideways like [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~jdaggett/images/ex5-macfan201007-p30-softbank-ipad.png), [Here](http://people.mozilla.org/~jdaggett/images/ex1-nikkei20100602-aft-p1-nikkei-heikin.png) the do interesting stuff like squish numbers on to a single line.

Comment: I'm just beginner level Japanese, So you'll have to research/ask native speakers. I find latin text vertically oriented in top-to-bottom Japanese easiest to read and I think it is the most common.